# How to add four views in a linearlayout in android?

Tags: android

I am working on quiz application and so I need to display a graph based on the marks obtained. But I am facing problem with adjusting the layouts. In the layout I am displaying the graph and below that I need to display like:

```
image correct = 13
image wrong   = 4
image total   = 17
```

But I am unable to align them exactly in layout. Please any sugggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F7FBF7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/graph"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>


         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl22"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/v1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text=":" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/greenimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/correctleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:src="@drawable/green" >
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/correctleft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/v1"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Correct"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/correct"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/v1"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel10"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/v2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text=":" />

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/redimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/incorrectleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/red" >
            </ImageView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/incorrectleft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/correct"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/v2"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Incorrect"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/incorrect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/correct"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/v2"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel11"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/v3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/v2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text=":" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blueimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/totalleft"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/darkblue" >
            </ImageView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalleft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/incorrect"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/v3"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Omitted"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/incorrect"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/v3"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="#283790"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what have you done so far? you should post your code..

Comment: How about just 1 view and you actually "draw" your graph in there!

Comment: Can you post a picture so we can get a better idea of what your code is currently producing and your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert the last three items ( image lines in a list view)? in that case, here is the code for 2 listviews in one activity.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

     <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

      <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_view2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```